# Remove Chart.js chart padding

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

See this codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgwjMd

I've set the canvas width to 100%, and padding to 0, but there seems to be some intrinsic padding at work in chart.js. I've had a look through the documentation but I can't see any references to padding other than things like label padding.

I've tried editing it through the CSS, but that doesn't seem to be causing the problem.

```
canvas {
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

So its probably a javascript canvas rendering parameter issue.

Having no control over this padding makes designing a usable responsive site a complete pain.

If there isn't a solution to this, does anyone have any suggestions for alternative javascript charting packages that are good for responsive sites?

I have experience with d3, but that seems like overkill for a simple pie chart.

Comment: removing 5 whole pixels of padding is not the solution for creating a responsive template. why would you wan tot graphic to go all the way to the edge that would look awful.

Comment: Not really the question I was asking. The chart that Chart.js generates width is actually something like 50% of the canvas width. I want to know if there is a way to increase the chart width to 90% of the canvas width or something. Its not really a CSS question I suppose, probably more to do with the canvas rendering functions. Will edit question.

Comment: you cannot put a circle in a wide rectangle and expect it to go all the way to the edge. that isn;t how circles work. generally, they are round. however if you shrink the window the legend does go pretty much all the way to the edges.

Comment: But what's happening in chart.js that's stopping the circle from going all the way to the edge? I mean, I haven't specified a fixed height of the containing rectangle anywhere. Ideally I want the chart to have the same width of a container div (with the chart height adjusted automatically to fit), and then size the width of that container div responsively.

Comment: Correction - section in brackets should read: (with the container div height adjusted automatically to fit the chart in).

Comment: what you described sounds exactly like the behaviour of the chart when you turn on the responsive option (which it is in your fiddle). i think you will have to actually put the chart in context in your page and show what it's doing versus what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer - pretty easy one, just set the canvas height and width attributes (NOT CSS parameters) to the required aspect ratio and then it resizes automatically, whilst maintaining the ratio.

Comment: This is not the answer tho. Yes the container will size up to its parent but the chart within will not